# How to use MediaWiki::DumpFile to convert Wikipedia XML dump to HTML?

Tags: html, xml, perl, cpan, wikitext

On page [MediaWiki::DumpFile](http://search.cpan.org/~triddle/MediaWiki-DumpFile-0.2.2/lib/MediaWiki/DumpFile.pm#___top) following code is present:

```
  use MediaWiki::DumpFile;

  $mw = MediaWiki::DumpFile->new;

  $sql = $mw->sql($filename);
  $sql = $mw->sql(\*FH);

  $pages = $mw->pages($filename);
  $pages = $mw->pages(\*FH);

  $fastpages = $mw->fastpages($filename);
  $fastpages = $mw->fastpages(\*FH);

  use MediaWiki::DumpFile::Compat;

  $pmwd = Parse::MediaWikiDump->new;
```

I'm completely new to Perl and don't know what to do with $fastpages to save all HTML pages (or text, it doesn't matter) from XML dump. Can you help me? And what is *FH ?

Comment: While searching for extracting library I found this excellent page: http://medialab.di.unipi.it/wiki/Wikipedia_Extractor . It can be used instead of method in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used it but the documentation for [`MediaWiki::DumpFile::FastPages`](http://search.cpan.org/~triddle/MediaWiki-DumpFile-0.2.0/lib/MediaWiki/DumpFile/FastPages.pm) has the following example for printing the title and text of each article in a dump file:

```
use MediaWiki::DumpFile::FastPages;

$pages = MediaWiki::DumpFile::FastPages->new($file);
$pages = MediaWiki::DumpFile::FastPages->new(\*FH);

while(($title, $text) = $pages->next) {
  print "Title: $title\n";
  print "Text: $text\n";
}
```

This will write everything to `stdout`. When you create the `MediaWiki::DumpFile::FastPages` object, you can pass either a file *name*, e.g.

```
$file = "/path/to/dump/file";
$pages = MediaWiki::DumpFile::FastPages->new($file);
```

or a reference to a file *handle*, e.g.

```
open FH, "<", "/path/to/dump/file" or die "Failed to open file: $!";
$pages = MediaWiki::DumpFile::FastPages->new(\*FH);
```